# How to get HTML element value in Liquid

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am working on a Shopify store and want to get product's price as per the variant selection in product page. I would like to know how I can get HTML element's value using Liquid.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible - liquid stops as soon as the page is rendered. Extracting the value of the currently selected variant has to be done using javascript. You can display a certain variant's price on page load, but must update the page using JS whenever the user selects a different variant. Check the assets folder for javascript files where this might be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get element values, but `selected_variant` will get all of that Variant's attributes, including price:

```
{{ product.selected_variant.price | money }}
```